# If $f'(x)=f(x)+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ and $f(0) = 1,\,$ then what is the value of $\, \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> If $\displaystyle f'(x)=f(x)+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\,$ and $\,f(0) = 1.$ Then what is value of $\displaystyle \int f(x)\,dx\,?$

$\bf{My\; Try.}$ Let $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = A\;,$ Then $f'(x) = f(x)+A$

Now Diff. both side w. r.to $x\;,$ we Get $f''(x) = f(x).$

Now We will solve the differential equation,we will multiply both side by $f'(x)$ and Integrate it

$\displaystyle \int f''(x)\cdot f'(x)dx = \int f(x)\cdot f'(x)dx\Rightarrow \frac{(f'(x))^2}{2} = \frac{(f(x))^2}{2}+\frac{\mathcal{C}}{2}$

So $\displaystyle f'(x)=\pm \sqrt{f(x)+\mathcal{C}}\Rightarrow \int \frac{f^{'}(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)+\mathcal{C}}}dx=\pm \int 1dx$

Now I did not understand how can i solve it.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Careless error: $f''(x)=f'(x)$.

Comment: Setting $f(x)+c=u$, what do you get? (Don't know why my previous comment disappered)

Comment: To  David, I did not understand why $f''(x)\neq f'(x)$, plz explain it to me, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.

$$f'(x)=f(x)+A$$

The solution is:

$$f(x)=-A+c e^x$$

So 
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=-A + (e-1) c=A \implies c=\frac{2A}{e-1}$$

Comment: This solution is not complete. Take the condition $f(0)=1$ into account to replace $c$ in your last equation and solve for $A,$ or simply look at [Alfred Chern's answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/983744/386889)

Answer (score 3):

$$(f(x)+\int_0^1f(x)dx)'=f(x)+\int_0^1f(x)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x)+\int_0^1f(x)dx=e^x[1+\int_0^1f(x)dx]$$
$$\Rightarrow2\int_0^1f(x)dx=(e-1)[1+\int_0^1f(x)dx]$$
$$\Rightarrow\int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{e-1}{3-e}$$

Comment: (+1) but I would have added "and $f(0)=1$" before the first $\Rightarrow.$

Answer (score 2):

You get
$$
f''=f',
$$
and thus $f'(x)=c_1e^x$, and hence $f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2$.

Next
$$
f'=f+\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
$$
implies that
$$
c_1\mathrm{e}^x
=\big(c_1\mathrm{e}^x+c_2\big)+\big(c_1(\mathrm{e}-1)+c_2\big),
$$
and hence $2c_2=-c_1(\mathrm{e}-1)$, which means that the general expression of $f$ is
$$
f(x)=c_1\mathrm{e}^x-\frac{1}{2}c_1(\mathrm{e}-1)
$$
Incorporating now the initial condition $f(0)=1$,
we obtain that $c_1=\dfrac{2}{3-\mathrm{e}}$, and
$c_2=-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}-1}{3-\mathrm{e}}$, and
hence
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{2}{3-\mathrm{e}}\mathrm{e}^{x}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}-1}{3-\mathrm{e}}
$$
and finally
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}-1}{3-\mathrm{e}}.
$$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes indeed.